# Submit Form using AJAX in Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How to make the page not refresh after I submit with the help of using AJAX in LARAVEL 4?

//xx.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '/booking/unit', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'readForm']) }}
{{ Form::hidden('bookingid', $booking->id) }} 
{{ Form::hidden('unitid', $booking->unit) }} 
<button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$booking->id}}" type="submit">{{ $booking->status }}</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

alternative way i tried:

```
<form method="post" action="../booking/unit/" id="readForm" >
<input value="{{$booking->id}}" hidden name="bookingid" />
<input value="{{$booking->unit}}" hidden name="unitid" />
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="readBtn" >{{ $booking->status }}</button>
</form>
```

//js

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$("#readForm").submit(function(){
    data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "../booking/unit", 
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

});
```

my page is still refreshing. why?

**UPDATES [22nd July 2015]**
I actually have multiple table rows with the forms and the forms are having the same id. that caused the refreshing happened except for the first row of the form. I have changed the form id to class and this is solved! Thank you everyone! You guys are awesome and the answers are valuable. I will be extra careful next time. :D

Comment: Try preventing `form submit`  like `$("#readForm").submit(function(event){event.preventDefault()});` followed by your normal code!!

Comment: Check the browser's console for errors.

Comment: @TheAlpha can't get to see console because the page has refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#readForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Have you tried e.preventDefault in your ajax function. this only will stops refreshing the page

Comment: `$("#readForm").submit(function(e){
    alert('Hurray..!');
});`

Does this work for you? If yes means leave a comment

Comment: So that something is wrong in your form. Do correct them. Or add full code. Have you tried normal form like `<form method="post" action"/booking/unit"></form>`

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you click a submit button in a form, it will reload automatically. It is default behaviour. So you need to override the behaviour.

```
$("#readBtn").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You have to capture the event in the call back of submit function and prevent it using **preventDefault()** method.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '/booking/unit', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'readForm']) }}
{{ Form::hidden('bookingid', $booking->id) }} 
{{ Form::hidden('unitid', $booking->unit) }} 
<button onclick="return false;" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$booking->id}}" type="submit">{{ $booking->status }}</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This will work i think.

Comment: im sorry to say that i can't add the onclick function to the button because i need to click the same button for another action.

Comment: Hmm. Try $('.btn-warning').click(function(){
e.preventDefault();
});

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent default

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$("#readForm").submit(function(e){

// prevent from submiting
e.preventDefault();

    data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "../booking/unit", 
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

});
```